# What is the status of the cfDNA ends?

Tags: dna, ligation

I am working on a protocol to ligate [cfDNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulating_free_DNA), extracted from blood, into some vector. I have looked into the literature but I cannot find any detail about the status of the ends of the cfDNA. Are they blunt or sticky? What is the enzyme responsible for cutting the genomic DNA into cfDNA?

I know I could blunt it anyway and proceed with a blunt-ligation. However, the amount of cfDNA I have is limited and I would like to avoid purification steps. So, if it tourn out that it is already blunt-ended I would save a step in the process.

Also, protocol aside, I really would like to know more about the cfDNA molecular details and which enzyme is generating it.

Any hint is very appreciated.